# Como fazer download de arquivo do SQL Server usando Servlet

Tags: java, sql-server, java-ee, servlet, download

Estou com uma aplicação básica onde salvo arquivos no banco `SQL Server` usando `Java`, a parte de inserir no banco eu já fiz, gostaria de saber como faço para 
fazer o download do arquivo que está no banco via `JSP`.

Como está armazenado no banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu servlet para fazer download:

```
package servlet;

import dao.ConnectionFactory;
import dao.FactoryDAO;
import interfaceDAO.IFileDAO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.FileMODEL;

/**
 *
 * @author Victor
 */
@WebServlet(name = "Download", urlPatterns = {"/Download"})
public class Download extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        Connection conn;
        IFileDAO dao = FactoryDAO.create_FileDAO();
        int id;
        FileMODEL attachment = null;
        conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        attachment = dao.searchById(id);

        try {
            byte[] b = attachment.getFILE_CONTENT();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("Downloads/aluno.xml"));
            fileOutputStream.write(b);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Download.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Download.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua o FileOutputStream  por OutputStream e indique no cabeçalho o Mime do arquivo. Segue abaixo:

```
 try {
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=aluno.xml");

    byte[] strBytes = attachment.getFILE_CONTENT();
    response.setContentLength(strBytes.length);
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write( strBytes );
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```